# Multi-key instance retrieval algorithm

Tags: algorithm, trie

I have a class Message which is as follows:

```
class Message{

String entity;
Boolean isAvailable;
.........

//getters and setters
.....
.....
}
```

Given a code,I have to find out all Message instances whose entity match on this code by the first 8 alphabets or more,and are 'Available'.
This looked a place where Trie would suit well.
However,given that the search is equally on 2 attributes - is there any algorithm which gives me a faster way to select?
Alternatively,is there a Trie variant which can accommodate multiple keys?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove it from the trie when `isAvailable` is set to false?

Alternatively, if you need to search `isAvailable == false` as well, then you could just have two tries. This provides O(n) lookup time dominated by the trie, so it's as fast as you can get using a trie (which does sound like the correct solution for your problem).

It's worth noting that "accommodate multiple keys" probably isn't what you're looking for, as this would refer to matching a `Message` that matches, say, `entity` and `entity2`. This is a little more involved, but can be accomplished by using a trie on `entity` and a trie on `entity2`, and upon lookup taking the intersection of the resultant set, which produces a linear time solution as well.